# Concatenate the elements in a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

How can I turn the following array below so it looks like example 2 using PHP.

Example 1 array.

```
Array ( [0] => &sub1=a1 [1] => &sub2=aa [2] => &sub3=glass-and-mosaics [3] => &sub4=guides-and-reviews [4] => &sub5=silent-movies [5] => &sub6=even-more-eastern-religions-and-philosophies )
```

Example 2.

```
&sub1=a1&sub2=aa&sub3=glass-and-mosaics&sub4=guides-and-reviews&sub5=silent-movies&sub6=even-more-eastern-religions-and-philosophies
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I edited the title to be more specific to your question.

Answer (score 3):

can use  [implode](http://www.php.net/implode)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function.

```
$arr = array(0 => '&sub1=a1',1 => '&sub2=aa');
$str = implode('',$arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

just do a `$myVar = implode('', $array);`

Answer (score 1):

If this is a query fragment of a URL, use `http_build_query` instead:

```
echo http_build_query(
   'sub1'=>'a1',
   'sub2'=>'aa',
   'sub3'=>'glass-and-mosaics',
   'sub4'=>'guides-and-reviews',
   'sub5'=>'silent-movies',
   'sub6'=>'even-more-eastern-religions-and-philosophies'
);
```